# showing that $f(z)=∑^\infty_0a_nz(z−z_0)^n$ is a power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

I want to show that $f(z)=∑^\infty_0a_nz(z−z_0)^n$ is a power series by putting it into the following form: $f(z)=∑^\infty_0b_n(z−z_0)^n$.

I've tried rewriting $z$ as $z-z_0+z_0$ to get $f(z)=∑^\infty_0a_n(z-z_0+z_0)(z−z_0)^n=∑^\infty_0a_n(1+\frac{z_0}{z-z_0})(z−z_0)^{n+1}$, but now there are two problems: (1) the function $f(z)$ is not not defined at $z=z_0$ and (2) I don't see where to go from here.

Can you please show me how to properly manipulate the expression into the desired typical power series form, as well as inform me on how to properly think about the "form" of a power series?

If this question is not clear, I hope I have at least expressed what it is I am not getting.

Comment: Split $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0+z_0)(z−z_0)^n$ into a sum of two power series in $z-z_0$. Adding two power series is not very hard. The title should be "showing that $f$ is *equal* to a power series" as it is not one strictly speaking.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Adding two power series is not very hard. The title should be "showing that f is equal to a power series" as it is not one strictly speaking."

Answer (score 2):

As reuns suggested in the comments, we can write
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz(z-z_0)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n[(z-z_0) + z_0](z-z_0)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^{n+1} + a_nz_0(z-z_0)^n.
$$
Split up these two summands into separate sums. The first term reads
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}(z-z_0)^n
$$
upon reindexing, and the second term is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz_0(z-z_0)^n = a_0z_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz_0(z-z_0)^n
$$
Hence
$$
f(z) = \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}(z-z_0)^n\right) + \left(a_0z_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz_0(z-z_0)^n\right) = a_0z_0+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n-1} + a_nz_0)(z-z_0)^n.
$$
Your desired $b_n$'s are therefore
$$
b_0 = a_0z_0, \text{ and } b_n = a_{n-1} + a_nz_0 \text{ for } n \geq 1.
$$